# c# MessageSecurityException in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, endpoint

I have a web service feature that I have been using for many years. Today they sent me a new certificate, a .cer file, which I inserted instead of the old one but I get this error:
(Translated with Google, sorry)

```
MessageSecurityException 
Failed to complete identity check for outgoing message.
The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'pddasl-coll.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it'
but the remote endpoint provided a DNS claim 'pdd-virtasl.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it'.
If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by specifying
explicitly the DNS identity 'pdd-virtasl.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it'
as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating the channel proxy.
```

I asked the owner of the web service and they told me that I have to make sure to ignore the error, but I don't know how. I tried to insert in the app.config: enableUnsecuredResponse = "true" but it didn't work.

This is the method for connecting to the web service:

```
    public static CVPClient Connect()
    {
        CVPClient oConsist = null;
        string cEndPoint = "https://pddasl-coll.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it:8181/aslba/CVPService";
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Leo.CertificateHandler;
        datiOperatore DataOp = Leo.OperatorData();//unimportant parameters
        datiApplicativo DataApp = Leo.AppData();//unimportant parameters
        var b = new CustomBinding();
        var sec = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement(
            new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never),
            new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient));
        sec.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
        sec.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
        sec.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        sec.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        sec.KeyEntropyMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityKeyEntropyMode.ServerEntropy;
        sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        b.Elements.Add(sec);
        b.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
        b.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(cEndPoint);
        oConsist = new CVPClient(b, ea);
        X509Certificate2 certSigned = Leo.GetSignedCert();//this returns my private certificate, not the one they replaced me

        string cPin = "123456";
        System.Security.SecureString SecurePIN = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char ch in cPin)
        { SecurePIN.AppendChar(ch); }
        var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certSigned.PrivateKey;
        string ContinerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
        string CspName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
        int CspType = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;
        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(CspType, CspName, ContinerName, new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(), SecurePIN);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider CSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);

        X509Certificate2 certUnsigned = Leo.GetUnSignedCertificate();//Here I read the new certificate

        oConsist.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certSigned;
        oConsist.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = certUnsigned;
        oConsist.Open();

        return oConsist;
    }
```

As you can see also here I have inserted **sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true**; The connection is successful but, as I said before, I get the error when I call the web service.
How can I solve the problem?

UPDATE:
Since the error tells me to explicitly assign the DNS identity 'pdd-virtasl.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it'
as the Identity property of EndpointAddress, I replaced this line:

```
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(cEndPoint);
```

with this:

```
DnsEndpointIdentity identity = new DnsEndpointIdentity(cEndPoint);
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(cEndPoint), identity, new AddressHeaderCollection());
```

but it doesn't work, I get the same error

Comment: You are failing TLS authentication.  The encryption mode you are using has to be compatible with the TLS version (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  The industry decided five years ago to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues.  Microsoft in June this year pushed a security update the disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and required clients to request only TLS 1.2/1.3.  The default version of TLS used when not specified in your c# code depends on version of VS and Version of windows.  I would use a sniffer to determine version of TLS being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is this:

```
            DnsEndpointIdentity identity = new DnsEndpointIdentity("pdd-virtasl.rmmg.rsr.rupar.puglia.it");
            EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(cEndPoint), identity, new AddressHeaderCollection());
```

You have to use the web service endpoint but specify the endopint contained in the certificate in the identity.